# How to make/preserve popcorn so that its taste and texture doesn't deteriorate within a day or two?

Tags: food-preservation, popcorn

I really love popcorn and usually pop it on the stove and eat it right away. However I'd like to make it ahead to save for snacks at work. I tried this once before and the kernels got a bit stale tasting, not very crisp. Are there any techniques for making popcorn that can hold up for a day or two, and how long would it last?

Comment: Air, moisture, and time are not friends to popcorn once it is popped.  

If you own a vacuum packing tool that supports jars, you might try putting it in a jar under vacuum.  If you try to do it in a bag, the popcorn will certainly be crushed :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you coat the popcorn (with caramel, etc), I know of no way, other than SAJ's vacuuming idea, which is quite a good one, imo.